# Anydesk 6.2.1 is not working properly on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: kubuntu, remote-desktop, anydesk

Anydesk 6.2.1 is having problems connecting to the remote computer. It doen't show any error but take endless time to connect.

Answer (score -1):

Switch to an older version Anydesk 6.1.0. by installing
anydesk_6.1.0-1_amd64.deb

```
sudo apt-get purge anydesk
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt update
sudo apt list --upgradable
sudo apt upgrade -y
# Download anydesk_6.1.0-1_amd64.deb from https://download.anydesk.com/linux/
sudo dpkg -i anydesk_6.1.0-1_amd64.deb 
sudo apt update
sudo dpkg -i anydesk_6.1.0-1_amd64.deb 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt --fix-broken install
sudo dpkg -i anydesk_6.1.0-1_amd64.deb 
sudo apt install -f
sudo apt update
```